# Add image in popup from json Url or image folder?

Tags: leaflet, image, popup, url

Added individual url and image for 21 places in json file.
Am trying to add image in my popup. Image shows up but broken in the popup. Not sure where in the code the error is??

(Same error for every popup, I rather load image from url, less space in project, but more control over pic if internal.)

My code:

```
var markerStyle = {
    radius: 3,
    fillColor: "#E4007C",
    color: "#E2062C",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 0.9,
    fillOpacity: 0.7
};
         
var city = L.geoJson(cities, {
pointToLayer: function (features, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, markerStyle)
            .bindPopup("<center><img src='images/cityPic/" 
            + features.properties.cityPic 
            + "' style='width:200px;height:300x;'></center>" 
            + "<p><b> "+features.properties.city + "</b><br/>" 
            + "County: " + features.properties.admin_name + "<br/>" 
            + "Population: " + features.properties.population + "</p>" 
            + "<a href ='https://www.google.se/maps/@59.3036556,17.9778991,14z'><b> GET HERE </b></a>");
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your [`bindPopup`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#popup), make sure the call to the GeoJSON property matches its actual name:

```
var markerStyle = {
    radius: 3,
    fillColor: "#E4007C",
    color: "#E2062C",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 0.9,
    fillOpacity: 0.7
};
         
var city = L.geoJson(cities, {
pointToLayer: function (features, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, markerStyle)
            .bindPopup("<center><img src='images/cityPic/" 
            + features.properties.cityPic  // <-- this doesn't exist in your geojson object
            + "' style='width:200px;height:300x;'></center>" 
            + "<p><b> "+features.properties.city + "</b><br/>" 
            + "County: " + features.properties.admin_name + "<br/>" 
            + "Population: " + features.properties.population + "</p>" 
            + "<a href ='https://www.google.se/maps/@59.3036556,17.9778991,14z'><b> GET HERE </b></a>");
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

The line `features.properties.cityPic` doesn't match the `features.properties.pic` property of your [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) object which holds an image name `stockholm.jpg`.